# Equation centering

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I m using a scientific journals template.

```
\begin{equation} 

\end{equation}
```

command does not centering the equation. How may I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you used `fleqn` anywhere? But without seeing a compilable document example we cannot help much.

Comment: if the journal has chosen left aligned equations it is their choice and presumably there is no issue to solve. generic classes like `article` have a `fleqn` option but journal classes typically force the journal style.